# Create and Update no longer working. Any suggestions? Or reasons why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, crud

I'm attempting to build a simple blog type app to learn ruby on rails. Create used to work, but after adding the edit/update function, both create and edit doesn't work. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Edit doesn't update with the new data and Create no longer accepts new data.  Ex: creating a new post will result in a blank post no matter what is written and when adding new text to an old post will not change the post after hitting submit.

My controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)

    if @post.save(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(post_params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    params.permit(:title, :detail)
end
```

Both edit and create html files render a form page:

```
<div class="section">
    <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :title %>
       <%= f.input :detail %>
       <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add the contents of `post_params` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)  # use Post.new, don't create already
  if @post.save                  # if above Post is saved then redirect
    redirect_to @post 
  else 
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])  #use params[:id], not post_params[:id]
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])           #use params[:id] to find the post
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)  #use post_params for attributes
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def edit
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])        #use params[:id] to find post
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :detail)
  # Don't permit the ID as you don't want to change the ID.
end
```

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: Please compare your code and the one I wrote. It had some difference. You should not use the post_params[:id] for update. use params[:id] instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. I changed my code, but its still doing the same thing. Nothing changed.

Comment: I do have a show action, I just decided not to add it since I didn't think it was relevant to the problem. I have added it now and simplified the form so it doesn't have any too much extra html.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is your `post_params` method. I'm guessing you'll have to require the `:post` key before permitting its attributes. Usually, simple_form (and other form engines) will assemble the payload like this:

```
{
  "utf8": "✓",
  "authenticity_token": "...",
  "commit": "Create Post",
  "post": {
    "title": "Opa",
    "content": "teste"
  }
}
```

so if you `params.permit(:title, :detail, :id)` you will get an empty hash. And that's probably the reason the post is being saved with empty attributes.

You will have to

```rb
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :detail)
```

by default, the url params (those you define in the routes like `/posts/:id`) are already permitted, so you don't have to permit nor require it.

Comment: Unfortunately when I add require(:post) it returns the error: param is missing or the value is empty: post